# Website dont show eny CSS style on mobile device

Tags: html, css, mobile

On the desktop everything works great but on mobile devices it doesn't accept a single CSS change.

(Background, writing on the pictures, text colour etc.)

My homepage is: https://julianjonathanjohnson.ch/

```
  What have I tried so far: 
- images reduced to far below 5Mb
- body{background:green}
body:after{content: "mobile"}


@media screen and (min-width:481px){
    body{background:blue}
    body:after{content: "481px and larger"} 
}
@media screen and (min-width:769px){
    body{background:red}
    body:after{content: "769px and larger"} 
}
```

My HTML is: (a mess ithink but order in chaos for me :D )

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> DogeWall </title>
    
    <script src="js.js"></script>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS.css"> 

    
</head>



<body id="page-wrap">
  
 <h1>Hello dear DOGE HODLER <br> Welcome to DogeWall <br> the hall of fame <br> for the first to walk on the moon.</h1>


        <ol>
<li class="P1">
         
<div class="TxtBild1">
        
        <img src="Bilder/MoonBg.jpg"  width="500" height="300">
        <span> <strong> citation example: Name: Date:  <br>
        <em> "To the moon and much further"</em></strong> </span>
        <span1> <ul>
            <strong>I take with me <br> to the MOON: </strong> 
            <li>Toiletpaper</li>
            <li>Fish snacks</li>
            <li>Bulldozer</li>
            <li> I donated <br> xxxyyz DOGE</li>
        </ul> </span1></div></li>
        
        <li class="P2">
         
<div class="TxtBild2">
        
        <img src="Bilder/MoonBg.jpg"  width="500" height="300">
        <span> <strong> citation example: Name: Date:  <br>
        <em> "To the moon and much further"</em></strong> </span>
        <span2> <ul>
            <strong>I take with me <br> to the MOON:</strong> 
            <li>Toiletpaper</li>
            <li>Fish snacks</li>
            <li>Bulldozer</li>
            <li> I donated <br> xxxyyz DOGE</li>
        </ul> </span1></div></li>
    
    </ol></body></html>
```

And my CSS is :

```
#page-wrap {
    width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
}

body {
    background-image:url("Bilder/MoonBg.jpg") ;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
   
    color: bisque;
    
    
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
.TxtBild1 {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    border: 5px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    
    
}
.TxtBild1 span {
    background-color: silver;
    background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.5);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    line-height: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Garamond, serif;
  border-radius: 50%;
    
}
.TxtBild1 img{
    display: block;
    
}
span1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    line-height: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Garamond, serif;
  border-radius: 50%; 
}


.TxtBild2 {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    border: 5px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    
    
}
.TxtBild2 span {
    background-color: silver;
    background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.5);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    line-height: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Garamond, serif;
  border-radius: 50%;
    
}
.TxtBild2 img{
    display: block;
    
}
span2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    line-height: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Garamond, serif;
  border-radius: 50%; 
}
```

PS: The plan of my project is that it should look as simple everywhere as it does on the desktop.

I want to be able to easily duplicate the individual images with text on them, but still change their colour, background etc. easily, so I think my current chaotic looking approach is easily changeable.

EDIT:
The problem is found and funny, the code was all fine, my mobile device was the problem, other phones worked fine and when i used icognito on my phone it worked too, finally an problem with google options.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of editor are you using? You're missing a beginning `<head>` tag.
https://jsfiddle.net/qy58gwdu/
Should work...

Comment: I use visual studio :)